# Shortcut to create a var statement in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is there a shortcut to create a `var` statment with WebStorm? For example in the following line I wanna create `var parameter` when selecting `parameter`:

```
someFunctionCall(parameter);
```

expected result

```
var parameter;
someFunctionCall(parameter);
```

Comment: `Refactor` | `Extract` | `Variable`?

Comment: Yes, didn't notice that it works for this case to.

Comment: Btw. the shortcut is ⌥ + ⌘ + V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Refactor` | `Extract` | `Variable`. Shortcut would depend on the OS and selected keymap.